# Can blocking the aperture of a mobile phone speaker cause damage?

Tags: technology, mobile-phones, sound

A friend was sitting near another's ringing mobile phone, stoically ignoring the noise. When I advised him to cover the dynamic with a finger, he replied that it may break it.

Is it really so? I think the energy should be dissipated in finger/casing and is too weak to break anything anyway.

Managed to find a reference with [remotely] similar opinion, although here the aperture is covered to make it louder as opposed to silencing it http://www.e-katalog.ru/opinion_ie.php?resolvedName_=NOKIA-1280 "И динамик не стоит на обратной стороне заклеивать или закрывать пальцем,на много проще перевернуть телефончик обратной стороной к уху и слышимость становится просто-супер!А заклеенный динамик со временем испортится." -> "And you should not block the dynamic on the reverse side with finger or with duct tape. Simply turn around the device and lean the back side your ear - audibility is superb. And glued (with a duct tape) dynamic will eventually spoil."

Comment: Welcome to Skeptics! We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made.

Comment: This one looks certainly not widely held/notable. (I thought it is about any doubtful claims that can be confirmed or rejected).

Comment: What is the "aperture" of a mobile phone?

Comment: @Sklivvz - I think they mean a speaker opening, using the camera term to denote it (In optics, an aperture is a hole or an opening through which light travels).

Comment: @dvk, it could also be the mic, at least that's what I understood (also, is it the same thing as the "dynamic")?